# Is there a way to assign the AssemblyTitle in WPF to the Window Title?

Tags: wpf, assemblyinfo

I want to have the AssemblyTitle change whenever I change the Title of the main window in WPF. Im not sure how to do this?  Any suggestions?  Can I do this in the XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AssemblyTitleAttribute.Title is readonly so this is not an option.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute.title(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can I change the Assembly Title and then in turn it will change the Window Title?

Comment: No, you can only set it during build.

Comment: Is there a way to set the window title as the assembly title name when I build?

I want to be able to change the assembly title name and then rebuild and have the window title change to the new assembly title.

Comment: Sure, if you're using MVVM just assign to a property the Assembly title and bind that property to the window title or if you're only working in code behind, set the window title in its constructor.

Comment: I tried doing this:Title = Application.Current.MainWindow.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;  The only problem is that I need the Assembly Title in the Assembly Information and I keep getting the Assembly name.  I apologize if i'm being confusing by the way.

Comment: You have to get the attribute off the assembly, it's not a property like GetName().Name.

Comment: You have to use System.Reflection.  `AssemblyTitleAttribute title = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0] as AssemblyTitleAttribute;`
        `return title.Title;`